# WordPress Animation Adjustments

Tags: theme-development, images, css, pages, errors

I have a problem with my WordPress animations. https://cyals.com is the website Currently developing. I Use Elementor Page Builder to build my page. a man and a woman load with animations one by one on my page. I Used "Slide in Left" and "Slide in Right" animations as Entrance Animation in Motion Effects in Elementor. The woman load from the edge of the page. but I want to load it only inside the column. I don't Know How to do it. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS property to the column will hide the woman until she is inside the column. But there will probably be a delay while she animates in the hidden area.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```